# Saucer flying header and footer

Tags: html, pdf, header, footer, flying-saucer

I use the header and footer in saucer flying. It works well.
The current state works where I use the div with header or footer, I have from there until the end of the file header or footer.
I've tried this, but it doesn't work.
`{ content: element(header, last-except)}` or `{ content: element(header, first-except)}`

This is my code
style:

```
div.header {
   display: block; 
   text-align: center;
   position: running(header);
}

div.footer {
   display: block; 
   text-align: center;
   position: running(footer);
}

@page {
   @top-center { content: element(header) }
} 

@page {
   @bottom-center { content: element(footer) }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
</div>
```

I would like to have a header or footer only, for example from 2 to 5 pages of pdf.
Is there a way to stop the generation on each page of the pdf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With flying-saucer, you can only set a different header or footer for the first page, using the [`:first` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#first-pseudo).

```css
.header {position: running(header);}
.footer {position: running(footer);}

.headerfirst {position: running(headerfirst);}
.footerfirst {position: running(footerfirst);}

@page :first {
    @top-center { content: element(headerfirst) }
    @bottom-center { content: element(footerfirst) }
}
@page {
    @top-center { content: element(header) }
    @bottom-center { content: element(footer) }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `:last` pseudo-class doesn't work.